# Pycharm can't import Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

OS: macOS Sierra
Python ver.: installed 2.7.10 and then installed 3.5.2. (default setting 2.7.10 -> anyone know how to uninstall 2.7 or change the default setting to python 3.5 from python 2.7?)
Pycharm: 2016.2.3 (Project Interpreter 3.5.2)

I have been developing a web crawler based on BeautifulSoup library but there is an error message I could never get rid of. I installed beautifulsoup4 library in Pycharm and it can even load the library, but when it meets "find" function it keeps replying error message, "NoneType' object has no attribute 'find".

I attached the captured image of an error message.

Please help me to work this out.

Thanks. 
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BA0S.jpg)

Comment: It is AttributeError cause due to different reason not an issue of Pycharm , BeautifulSoup Library has been correctly imported, It would be an issue in the code

Answer (score 1):

The error message mean your object `title_section` is null,this was the real reason to your question,not the `Beautifulsoup` that can't be imported.

Moreover, your web page http://52.68.130.249/textboard/ does not have a tag `div` which contains the class `title_section`, then your `title_section` is null which leads to the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just proof-read carefully and fixed some typos...and finally it works!!

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your page, the problem is that you're looking for a div with class "title_section", but the actual div is named "title-section". The underscore should be a dash.

BeautifulSoup will return `None` if it can't find anything.

`title_section = content_table.find('div', class_='title_section')`

As there is no div with a `title_section` class, and BeautifulSoup's `find` method then returns `None`. So therefore your call sets the Python variable `title_section` to `None`.  Then when you call:

`title_section.find('h1')`

You're calling `None.find('h1')`, and the Python interpreter tells you that the NoneType object has no attribute find.

If you change the call to `content_table.find('div', class_='title-section')`, it will return a BeautifulSoup object, which you can call `find` on.